# Take image from image library

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want that my app will be able to take images automatically from the photos library without using UIImagePickerController, there is a way to do something like this in iphone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get access to user's albums and photos using [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class